# batch script works on win 7 but not win 2003

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to script and this question may sound very stupid but plesae help me with this. I think, i'm missing on some syntax here.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set file="C:\Documents and Settings\spati41\My Documents\My Tableau Repository\Datasources\OFFR STA Event Trigger Extract.tde"
set maxbytesize=900

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO SET size=%%~zA


if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (
    echo.File is ^< %maxbytesize% bytes
) ELSE (
    echo.File is ^>= %maxbytesize% bytes
)
```

This runs all fine and give expected output on Windows 7 but when I run same script on WINDOWS SERVER 2003 It gives me following error

> 900 was unexpected at this time.

Pleaes help. Thanks. Let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

The file may be in a different location on the other machine.

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=C:\Documents and Settings\spati41\My Documents\My Tableau Repository\Datasources\OFFR STA Event Trigger Extract.tde"

if not exist "%file%" echo "OFFR STA Event Trigger Extract.tde" file is missing & pause

set maxbytesize=900

FOR %%A IN ("%file%") DO SET size=%%~zA


if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (
    echo.File is ^< %maxbytesize% bytes
) ELSE (
    echo.File is ^>= %maxbytesize% bytes
)
```

Comment: I checked it, location is as per server machine. If I take the path and put it in run command - I'm able to access the file.

Comment: I altered the batch file - try it now.

Comment: Did that help at all?

Comment: thanks! I've to be on office network to test this code. I'll get back to you soon, thanks again.

Comment: I found something intersting. What I found is if there are any spaces in the file path location (in this is spaces between "\Documents" & "and" & "Settings" )- its showing error - and When I change the file patch location and make it in a such a way that there will be no spaces anywhere in entire file path location - then orginal script (shown in my question) is runnin all fine.

Comment: Any thoughts? I've some defualt server location form where I have to check the file for its size and those path has spaces in the path name. Plesae suggest.

Comment: The code I supplied should work with spaces - did you try it?